# Finding the items in a list by comparing with two string inputs

Tags: python

I have two string data like below

```
text1 = "hello how are you"
text2 = "hello how is professional life"
```

Then also I have a list of items which can/cannot be present in two strings like

```
test_data = ["are","how", "you","test","test2"]
```

Using this I will get items in `test_data` which are not present in `text1`.

```
[word for word in test_data if word not in text1]
```

Here the output obtained is

```
['are', 'you', 'test', 'test2']
```

In this case, `test` and `test2` are not present in the first and second string too. So I don't expect that in the result. So the expected result is

```
['are', 'you']
```

I am trying to find the data which is present only in `text1` and not in `text2`.

Comment: You question is not clear: Are trying to find all words of `test_data` that are not in `test1` but are in `test2`?

Comment: @Jacob A mistake in the sample data given. corrected it

Comment: I have added an answer, if helpful please mark as solution. ;)

Comment: your goal is not really clear.

Comment: I have uploaded a solution, that does uses the power of sets, and is more clearer, rather than a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend your approach by a second condition:

```
[word for word in test_data if word  in text1 and word not in text2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
text1 = "hello how are you"
text2 = "hello how is professional life"

a = text1.split()
b = text2.split()

# print an array that has the words that are not in the other array
print(list(set(a) - set(b)))
```

output:

```py
['are', 'you']
```